# To show different color on every row in a table based on condition in vf page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I need to show different color on every row based on condition in VF Page. How I will acheive this:
Below is the code:
Based on key value I need to show different color to every row.

```
<table>
<apex:repeat value="{!mapSurveyQuestionResponseFinal}" var="key" >
    <tr>
       <td  style="font-weight:bold;background-color:#e60000;color:white">{!key} 
        Total Score:</td>
       <apex:repeat value="{!mapSurveyQuestionResponseFinal[key]}" var="con">
           <td style="font-weight:bold;background-color:#e60000;color:white"> 
            {!Round(mapSurveyQuestionResponseFinal[key][con],1)}</td> 
       </apex:repeat>   

   </tr>
</apex:repeat>
<tr>
   <td  style="font-weight:bold;background-color:#e60000;color:white">Grand Total:</td>
   <apex:repeat value="{!mapGrandTotal}" var="gt">
       <td style="font-weight:bold;background-color:#e60000;color:white">{!Round(mapGrandTotal[gt],1)}</td>
   </apex:repeat>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using CASE method and assign class to VF element, for example:

```
<div class="{!CASE([key, 1, "yellow", 2, "red", 3, "green", "default")}">
```

But you need to add this for each row.

Answer (score 2):

Create different CSS Class for each Color Like -

```
<apex:page>
<style>
    .red{
        background: red;
    }
    .greeen{
        background: green;
    }
    .blue{
        background: blue;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat value="{!dataValue}" var="data">
                <tr class={! if(data.key == '1', 'red',if(data.key == '2', 'green','blue'))}>
                    <td>Avinash</td>
                    <td>Salesforce Consultant</td>
                </tr>
        </apex:repeat>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your if syntax isn't quite right, but if you fix it, I'm sure you'll get some positive feedback.

Comment: Ohh yeah, I missed one inner if. Thanks for pointing that out 